# How to apply split string to entire data set of excel in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge data sets, that I would like to apply this

```
getNumber = df['Permissions','Per'].str.split('-').str[1]`
```

on the entire dataset and not just on '***Permissions***' column, is there any way I could apply it on the entire dataset, instead of specifying it on every column. I am stuck on how to apply this operation to the entire data set and would appreciate any help

**in response to Tim's comment**,

my dataset is like this,

dataset in excel sheet:-

[image]

I would like to extract the numbers in every columns, so that the new dataset will be having just the numbers.

Comment: What is your actual desired output here?

Comment: the plan is to have a new or the same sheet of excel just to have the numbers and not the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
#setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['aaa-0.1', 'bbb-1.2'], 'col2': ['zzzz-0.8', 'abc-9.1']})

#      col1      col2
#0  aaa-0.1  zzzz-0.8
#1  bbb-1.2   abc-9.1

df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('-').str[1])

#  col1 col2
#0  0.1  0.8
#1  1.2  9.1
```

---

As [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) say in the comments, you can also convert to float. Simply add `.astype(float)`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('-').str[1]).astype(float)
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried to apply this on my code and it says, AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!.

Comment: @A'sriIdris try doing `df = df.astype(str)` before

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) which applies a function to every cell in the dataframe:

```
def splitVal(item):
    item = str(item).strip()     # converts to string and removes extra whitespace
    arr = item.split('-');       # splits string into array
    if item and len(arr) > 1:    # if item is not empty and > 1 elements in the array
        return item.split('-')[1]
    return item                  # otherwise return whatever was there

getNumber = df.applymap(splitVal)
```